# Next.js 14 with Next-auth 5 - although might be relevant for 4 as well - Session type not updating

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth, next.js14

just trying these new tools and when I try to use the auth() function to call my user data that I store in it, TS claims that user doesn't exist in Session even though I declared it. Here's my auth.ts:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { authConfig } from "./authconfig";
import { connectDb } from "./lib/utils";
import { User } from "./lib/models";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { UserType } from "./lib/types";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    user?: UserType;
  }
}

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface User {
    username: string;
    img: string;
  }
}

const login = async (credentials: Partial<Record<string, unknown>>) => {
  try {
    connectDb();
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: credentials.username });

    if (!user) throw new Error("Invalid credentials");

    const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
      credentials.password as string,
      user.password
    );

    if (!isPasswordCorrect) throw new Error("Invalid credentials");

    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error("Login failed");
  }
};

export const { signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  ...authConfig,
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const user = await login(credentials);
          return user;
        } catch (error) {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, user }) {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.username = user.username;
        session.user.img = user.img;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
});
```

And here is where I call the auth() function:

```
import { MdLogout } from "react-icons/md";
import styles from "./sidebar.module.scss";
import MenuLink from "./menuLink/menuLink";
import Image from "next/image";
import { MENU_ITEMS } from "@/app/data/menuItems";
import { auth, signOut } from "@/app/auth";
import { authProvider } from "./authProvider";

const Sidebar = async () => {
  const { user } = await auth();
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.user}>
        <Image
          className={styles.userImage}
          priority
          src={user?.img || "/noavatar.png"}
          alt=""
          width="50"
          height="50"
        />
        <div className={styles.userDetail}>
          <span className={styles.username}>{user?.username}</span>
          <span className={styles.userTitle}>Administrator</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul className={styles.list}>
        {MENU_ITEMS.map((category) => (
          <li key={category.title}>
            <span className={styles.category}>{category.title}</span>
            {category.list.map((item) => (
              <MenuLink item={item} key={item.title} />
            ))}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <form
        action={async () => {
          "use server";
          await signOut();
        }}
      >
        <button className={styles.logout}>
          <MdLogout />
          Log out
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

So you can clearly see that I declare my user object into the Session but TS still throws the error saying: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Session | null'. Could you please tell me what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

`session` may be `null` so `session.user` may cause errors.
If your error is only

> Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Session | null'

Try `session?.user` may solve your problem.